# Does Apple's Wiki Server support forums?

Tags: apple

Does anyone know if the apple wiki server support forums?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't think so or it wouldn't be a wiki server. Wiki's are different from forums.

That said, leave it to marketing to mess with definitions. [Here's the page](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/wiki-server.html) describing features.

Also, [this document](http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/Extending_Your_Wiki_Server.pdf) doesn't have the word "forum" in it anywhere.

So I'd guess again that it doesn't specifically have a forum system built in to the wiki server, but depending on what your actual goals are, the Wiki does support some form of blogging and RSS subscriptions, depending on the version you're talking about. If you want a specific forum server (bulletin board style) you'll probably have to install something else, and suggesting it directly here in this question would end up being a subjective argument unrelated to the original question; you might want to post another question about suggestions for a forum server (with a description of what you're hoping to accomplish and what features you're specifically looking for) as another question along with your version of OS X Server.

Comment: Yeah it supports blogs so I figured it might... but I dont hink it does...

Answer (score 0):

I have an install OS X Server (Snow Leopard) and it definitely does not support forums.